# Is it possible to use the html `popover` attribute in a react element

Tags: reactjs, popover

I am searching if the [popover API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/popover) is available in react and it seeems not to be.

```html
<button popovertarget="my-popover">Open Popover</button>

<div popover id="my-popover">Greetings, one and all!</div>
```

i've searched online and haven't found any resources on how to do this using jsx alone

Answer (score 1):

React itself doesn't have a built-in popover component in its core API. However, there are several third-party libraries and components available in the React ecosystem that offer popover functionality.